# awk print rows of CSV file on condition?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a CSV file that has this values:

```
A     B       C
1    cat      cat
2    mouse    pig
3    dog      dog
```

How can i write an awk code that only prints rows where col A = col C?

Output i hope to get:

```
A     B       C
1    cat      cat
3    dog      dog
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is pretty simple

```
$ awk '$2==$3' file
1    cat      cat
3    dog      dog
```

- `$2==$3` Checks if the second field, `$2` is equal to third field, `$3`. If yes, `awk` takes the default action to print the entire record, line.

Comment: and if not equal it is: awk '$2 != $3' file ?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and check ;)

Answer (score 0):

awk '!/2/ {print $0}' file  
A     B       C  
1       cat     cat  
3       dog     dog

Realized I have to look into advanced help to get the output in order, but failed for the tabulator.  
Claes